# What is the meaning of "centrifugilillion" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "centrifugilillion" in the following sentence,

> If you had a fortune of umpteen-**centrifugilillion** dollars, what
> would you do with it

?

(Source : Disney's Uncle Scrooge: "Only a Poor Old Man)

Does "centrifugilillion" mean "centrifugal million" ?
What does "centrifugilillion" mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean "centrifugal million." It is a playful formation like "[**gazillion**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gazillion)" or "[**kajillion**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kajillion#:%7E:text=kajillion%20(plural%20kajillions),unspecified%20large%20number%20(of).)" which both mean **an unspecified enormous number.** The addition of more syllables is likely used here to give an impression that the number is even larger.

**[Umpteen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/umpteen)** means the same -- a large indefinite number.